# Monitor changes made by a desktop app to a file created by my Windows Store app

Tags: file-upload, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, file-access

I'm making a Windows Store app that gets files from a server and store it locally for quick access. I also want to make it sync the file with Dropbox and push changes to Dropbox if the user make any. I looked into CachedFileUpdater and it seems to work if I use another Windows Store app to edit the file. However I ran into a great trouble trying to monitor changes made by a desktop app. This matters a lot because many files are office documents and Office 2013 is available to Windows RT and I would also like the app to be available to Windows 8.

First I tried to use CachedFileUpdater on all files but when I open the file using a desktop app, it will be opened in read-only mode and I can't save it in desktop mode. If I dont use it if the user chooses to open it with desktop app, the change will be saved but later my app won't be able to access that file somehow. I guess it is because the owner changes to the desktop app. Now not only I seem to have no way to monitor the file changes, but also can't I access those changes once it is modified by a desktop app.\

Is there some trick that may help? Thank you very much!

Comment: I figured out that the permission problem is caused by Adobe Reader. When it saves a version of a file, it will replace the old file with a new file which is created by itself instead of modifying the data inside. Therefore my app will lose the control over that file. This can be solved by using some other software, but I don't want to restrict the user on what software he can use. So I'm still look forward to a solution to this problem, if there is any.